# Python - append no mesmo DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tenho o seguinte codígo para extrair dados do yahoo que funciona perfeitamente.
O meu problema é que queria inserir todos os dados em uma mesma tabela, toda vez que ele entrar no **FOR** ele ir add à tabela, mas não estou conseguindo.

Obrigado pela ajuda desde já.

```
for codigo_acao in acoes_ibov["Papel"]:
print("Acessando informações da ação: ",codigo_acao)



url = "https://br.financas.yahoo.com/quote/"+ codigo_acao +".SA/history?period1=1170288000&period2=4117305600&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)


acao = pd.read_html(r.text ,decimal = ",", thousands = "." )

acao = acao[0].iloc[1:-1,:2]

informacoes_1= acao.insert(loc= 0,column="Papel",value=codigo_acao)
print("Informações")
display(acao)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o append do pandas, nesse caso foi criado um novo data frame para ir adicionando os resultados a ele:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

header = {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

# novo data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Papel','Símbolo','Nome'])

acoes_ibov = ['AAPL','FB']

for codigo_acao in acoes_ibov:
    print("Acessando informações da ação: ", codigo_acao)

    url = "https://br.financas.yahoo.com/quote/"+ codigo_acao +".SA/history?period1=1170288000&period2=4117305600&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"

    r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

    acao = pd.read_html(r.text ,decimal = ",", thousands = "." )
    acao = acao[0].iloc[1:-1,:2]
    acao.insert(loc=0, column="Papel", value=codigo_acao)
    df = df.append(acao)
    
display(df.head())
```

Coloquei as acoes_ibov pois você não forneceu.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu caro, não coloquei as ações por que pego ela de um csv. Mas sua resposta me ajudou muito a solucionar este problema!

Comment: @DênisSuenaga por nada! Que bom que resolveu o problema! Grande abraço!